# Piping shasum to grep, but grep returning all lines of piped input, even ones that don't match

Tags: grep, checksum, sha256

I'm trying to script the download of the [node.js source](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.10.26.tar.gz) and [corresponding SHASUMS256.txt](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS256.txt), checksum it, grep for OK, and return no results just exit code 0 on success using grep's -q flag:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.10.26.tar.gz
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS256.txt
sha256sum -c SHASUMS256.txt|grep -q OK
```

However, grep is returning a selection of the non-matching lines "no such file or directory" errors (though not all, confusingly):

```
> sha256sum -c SHASUMS256.txt|grep -q OK 
sha256sum: node-v0.10.26-darwin-x64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
sha256sum: node-v0.10.26-darwin-x86.tar.gz: No such file or directory
sha256sum: node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
sha256sum: node-v0.10.26-linux-x86.tar.gz: No such file or directory
sha256sum: node-v0.10.26-sunos-x64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
sha256sum: node-v0.10.26-sunos-x86.tar.gz: No such file or directory
sha256sum: node-v0.10.26-x86.msi: No such file or directory
sha256sum: node-v0.10.26.pkg: No such file or directory
sha256sum: node.exe: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what the problem is here?  All I want from this script is return code 0 if the checksum succeeds (eg grep matches OK), or return code non-0 if it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When you pipe the output of a command as input to other command, only `stdout` of first command is passed as `stdin` to the second command.
- The lines you see are sent by the `sha256sum` program to `stderr`.
- You can verify that by sending `stderr` of `sha256sum` command also to `grep` by

  ```
  sha256sum -c SHASUMS256.txt 2>&1 |grep -q OK
  ```

Hope that helps.